# Formik Accessing values to pass on press of button

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to implement Form Wizard multistep. When I try to press the back button. I would like to pass the current form values to the previous step.

```
<Formik
      validationSchema={stepTwoValidationSchema}
      initialValues={props.data}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
  
        <Form>
          <p>Email</p>
          <Field name="email" />
          <ErrorMessage name="email" />

          <p>Password</p>
          <Field name="password" />
          <ErrorMessage name="password" />

          <button type="button" onClick={() => props.prev(values)}>
            Back
          </button>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
        
    </Formik>
```

But the values are coming as `undefined` is there anyway to do it without destructuring the values around the  and then passing the values. like below.

{({ values }) => (

.......
<button type="button" onClick={() => props.prev(values)}>
Back

.......

)}

How can I pass the value to the props?

```
onClick={() => props.prev(values)}
```

Comment: This should work... perhaps your initial values don't match include all fields? What's different between your code and this Sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/send-values-back-mtc21